# Onesignal making user appear 'active' every hour

Tags: react-native, onesignal

I am currently segmenting users by a location filter. However the location is only updated if the mobile app is in foreground. Is there a way to mimic the user's last activity / currently location every hour even if the app is in the background? I am currently using React Native.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the player / user record with the last location through the REST API by sending `lat` and `long`.
https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#edit-device

You will need to use a plugin or your own native code to get the location of the device in the background.